# My responsive site shows differently on mobile device

Tags: mobile, web, device, responsive

Instead of a home page showing up on a mobile device, I get to a page that has a website name and the words "View Website". Once you click on that then you get to the proper home page. Any clue why this is happening? Here is site: modernpriscilla.net

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing on mobile is the mobile version of your site. If your main/full website can support mobile layouts, then you might have to disable that option depending on what service you use to create the website.

It looks like you're using Wordpress, so check out this link:
https://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/mobile-themes/